# Android Sliding tab layout is not working

Tags: android

hey i am new to android development. i want to create sliding tab layout in my app. but when i run my application. it stops and says Unfortunately app has stopped working. here is my code where i want to show it

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import tabs.SlidingTablayout;


public class NewsFeed extends ActionBarActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
NavigationDrawer drawerFragment;
private ViewPager mPager;
private SlidingTablayout mTabs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_appbar);
    toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    drawerFragment=new NavigationDrawer();
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
   drawerFragment.setUp((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);

    mPager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(new myPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    mTabs=(SlidingTablayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater= getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_actionbar, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.search_id) {
        Toast msg = Toast.makeText(NewsFeed.this, "search selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        msg.show();

        return true;
    }
    if (id==R.id.info_id){
        Toast msg = Toast.makeText(NewsFeed.this, "info selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        msg.show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
class myPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    String[] tabs;
    public myPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        tabs=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        MyFragment myFragment=MyFragment.getInstance(position);

        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
public static class MyFragment extends Fragment{
    private TextView textView;
    public static MyFragment getInstance(int position){
        MyFragment myFragment=new MyFragment();
        Bundle args=new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position",position);
        myFragment.setArguments(args);
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
        textView=(TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.position);
        Bundle bundle=getArguments();
        if(bundle!=null){
            textView.setText("The Page currently Selecte"+bundle.getInt("position"));
        }

        return layout;
    }
}
```

}

this is my sliding tablayout.java class

```
package tabs;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SlidingTablayout extends HorizontalScrollView {

public interface TabColorizer {
    int getIndicatorColor(int position);

}

private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

private int mTitleOffset;

private int mTabViewLayoutId;
private int mTabViewTextViewId;
private boolean mDistributeEvenly;

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private SparseArray<String> mContentDescriptions = new SparseArray<String>();
private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

public SlidingTablayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public SlidingTablayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public SlidingTablayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);


    setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    setFillViewport(true);

    mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

    mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
    addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}


public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
    mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
}

public void setDistributeEvenly(boolean distributeEvenly) {
    mDistributeEvenly = distributeEvenly;
}


public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
    mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
}

public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
    mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
}


public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
    mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
    mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
}


public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

    mViewPager = viewPager;
    if (viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
        populateTabStrip();
    }
}

protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
            outValue, true);
    textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
    textView.setAllCaps(true);

    int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

    return textView;
}

private void populateTabStrip() {
    final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View tabView = null;
        TextView tabTitleView = null;

        if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {

            tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                    false);
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
        }

        if (tabView == null) {
            tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
        }

        if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
        }

        if (mDistributeEvenly) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = 0;
            lp.weight = 1;
        }

        tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
        tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
        String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
        if (desc != null) {
            tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
        }

        mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
        if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
            tabView.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
}

public void setContentDescription(int i, String desc) {
    mContentDescriptions.put(i, desc);
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    if (mViewPager != null) {
        scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
    }
}

private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
    final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
    if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
        return;
    }

    View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
    if (selectedChild != null) {
        int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

        if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {

            targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
        }

        scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
    }
}

private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private int mScrollState;

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
            return;
        }

        mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

        View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
        int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                : 0;
        scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                    positionOffsetPixels);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        mScrollState = state;

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
            scrollToTab(position, 0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
        }
        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
        }
    }

}

private class TabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
this is my slidingtabstrip code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

class SlidingTabStrip extends LinearLayout {

private static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 0;
private static final byte DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x26;
private static final int SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS = 3;
private static final int DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR = 0xFF33B5E5;

private final int mBottomBorderThickness;
private final Paint mBottomBorderPaint;

private final int mSelectedIndicatorThickness;
private final Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint;

private int mSelectedPosition;
private float mSelectionOffset;

private SlidingTablayout.TabColorizer mCustomTabColorizer;
private final SimpleTabColorizer mDefaultTabColorizer;

SlidingTabStrip(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

SlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setWillNotDraw(false);

    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.colorForeground, outValue, true);
    final int themeForegroundColor = outValue.data;

    int defaultBottomBorderColor = setColorAlpha(themeForegroundColor,
            DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA);

    mDefaultTabColorizer = new SimpleTabColorizer();
    mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR);

    mBottomBorderThickness = (int) (DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
    mBottomBorderPaint = new Paint();
    mBottomBorderPaint.setColor(defaultBottomBorderColor);

    mSelectedIndicatorThickness = (int) (SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
    mSelectedIndicatorPaint = new Paint();
}

void setCustomTabColorizer(SlidingTablayout.TabColorizer customTabColorizer) {
    mCustomTabColorizer = customTabColorizer;
    invalidate();
}

void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {

    mCustomTabColorizer = null;
    mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(colors);
    invalidate();
}

void onViewPagerPageChanged(int position, float positionOffset) {
    mSelectedPosition = position;
    mSelectionOffset = positionOffset;
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    final int height = getHeight();
    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    final SlidingTablayout.TabColorizer tabColorizer = mCustomTabColorizer != null
            ? mCustomTabColorizer
            : (SlidingTablayout.TabColorizer) mDefaultTabColorizer;


    if (childCount > 0) {
        View selectedTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition);
        int left = selectedTitle.getLeft();
        int right = selectedTitle.getRight();
        int color = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition);

        if (mSelectionOffset > 0f && mSelectedPosition < (getChildCount() - 1)) {
            int nextColor = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition + 1);
            if (color != nextColor) {
                color = blendColors(nextColor, color, mSelectionOffset);
            }


            View nextTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition + 1);
            left = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getLeft() +
                    (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * left);
            right = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getRight() +
                    (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * right);
        }

        mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(color);

        canvas.drawRect(left, height - mSelectedIndicatorThickness, right,
                height, mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
    }

    // Thin underline along the entire bottom edge
    canvas.drawRect(0, height - mBottomBorderThickness, getWidth(), height, mBottomBorderPaint);
}

private static int setColorAlpha(int color, byte alpha) {
    return Color.argb(alpha, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
}


private static int blendColors(int color1, int color2, float ratio) {
    final float inverseRation = 1f - ratio;
    float r = (Color.red(color1) * ratio) + (Color.red(color2) * inverseRation);
    float g = (Color.green(color1) * ratio) + (Color.green(color2) * inverseRation);
    float b = (Color.blue(color1) * ratio) + (Color.blue(color2) * inverseRation);
    return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
}

private static class SimpleTabColorizer implements SlidingTablayout.TabColorizer {
    private int[] mIndicatorColors;

    @Override
    public final int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
        return mIndicatorColors[position % mIndicatorColors.length];
    }

    void setIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mIndicatorColors = colors;
    }
}
```

}

here is my LogCat

```
02-29 22:37:41.472 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-29 22:37:41.752 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
02-29 22:37:41.752 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 373: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
02-29 22:37:41.752 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-29 22:37:41.752 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
02-29 22:37:41.752 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 395: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
02-29 22:37:41.752 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-29 22:37:41.862 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-29 22:37:41.862 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41754c08)
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings, PID: 6653
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings.NewsFeed}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498)
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179)
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings.NewsFeed.onCreate(NewsFeed.java:44)
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5484)
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498) 
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179) 
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324) 
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641) 
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288) 
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104) 
02-29 22:37:41.872 6653-6653/com.example.mubbasher.howdy_sendgreetings E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me

Comment: what is line no 44 in NewsFeed.java?

Comment: are you using eclipse for this?

Comment: no i m using android studio @RobertConley

Comment: A null pointer exception is raised on line no 44 in NewsFeed.java..could you please tell which line is that..

Comment: in that line i have added a adapter for my veiwpager. and fragmentManager that is defined below is passed as argument @Lal

Comment: tell me the exact line @Bebo

Comment: Line 83 is the fragementManager line @Lal

Comment: not 83..line no 44 in NewsFeed.java

Comment: in line 44 mPager.setAdapter(new myPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager())); i have set the adapter for my mpager and passed the FragmentManager as argument . that is defined in line 83 that is  public myPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            tabs=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
mTabs=(SlidingTablayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);
```

Your mTabs is throwing NPE. Please recheck your id of SlidingTablayout once or use fully qualified name of SlidingTablayout in your xml where you are defining this in the xml.